# Not able to perform Group-by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, sql-order-by

Trying to filter the details

Need the only row which has max `BookingVersion` group by `shipmentNumber, shipmentDate,`

```
select max(BookingVersion) BookingVersion, flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate, FlightOffPoint, IIF(BookingStatusCode = 'XX', 'XX','SS') BookingStatusCode
from Exp_BookingDelta where flightid='625436' 
group by flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate, FlightOffPoint, BookingStatusCode  
order by max(BookingVersion) desc
```

Can anyone please explain, what I'm missing?

**Current results:**

```
BookingVersion  flightId    shipmentNumber  shipmentDate    FlightOffPoint  BookingStatusCode
4               625436      61823647238     2019-12-04      LHR             XX
2               625436      61823647238     2019-12-04      LHR             SS
1               625436      61826374895     2019-12-06      LHR             XX
0               625436      61825364780     2019-11-26      LHR             SS
0               625436      61825364791     2019-11-26      LHR             SS
0               625436      61825364802     2019-11-26      LHR             SS
0               625436      61826374895     2019-12-06      LHR             SS
```

**Expecting results:**

```
BookingVersion  flightId    shipmentNumber  shipmentDate    FlightOffPoint  BookingStatusCode
4               625436      61823647238     2019-12-04      LHR             XX
1               625436      61826374895     2019-12-06      LHR             XX
0               625436      61825364780     2019-11-26      LHR             SS
0               625436      61825364791     2019-11-26      LHR             SS
0               625436      61825364802     2019-11-26      LHR             SS
```

Comment: And the problem is? Please add your query and the error you get.

Comment: Please your query, what you have tried so far

Comment: @juergend Added query.

Comment: @MukeshArora Added.

Comment: Can you then explain your logic as to how the "expected" rows would be returned?

Comment: The issue is in your query is booking status code field as it may unique, if you will remove that field from the group by and select, you will get the desired result for the rest of the fields, or you can put the aggregate function on booking status code field like max. let us know how you want to use this field, we can help you to write query accordingly.

Comment: The problem is your 'BookingStatusCode' returning different results for 'BookingVersion' 4 and 2, that is why you get them on two separate rows. We cannot see the underlying data, so cannot see if this is indeed expected or not - but never the less, that is the reason for your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
   max(BookingVersion) BookingVersion, flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate, FlightOffPoint, MAX(BookingStatusCode) BookingStatusCode
from
   Exp_BookingDelta where flightid='625436' 
group by flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate, FlightOffPoint
order by max(BookingVersion) desc
```

or

```
select 
    max(BookingVersion) BookingVersion, flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate,
    IIF((select count(*) from Exp_BookingDelta b where b.FlightId=a.FlightId and b.ShimpmentNumber=a.ShimpmentNumber)>0, 'XX', 'SS') BookingStatusCode
from 
    Exp_BookingDelta where flightid='625436' 
group by flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate, FlightOffPoint  
order by max(BookingVersion) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a window function to find the specific records you want.  Like:

```
;with c as (select BookingVersion, flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate, FlightOffPoint, IIF(BookingStatusCode = 'XX', 'XX','SS') BookingStatusCode
                 , row_number() over (partition by shipmentNumber order by BookingVersion desc) rn
              from Exp_BookingDelta
             where flightid='625436')
select BookingVersion, flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate, FlightOffPoint, BookingStatusCode
  from c
 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this query as per mention your expected output I'm prepared for example.

**Note: Please change this query as per your actual query.**

> Query

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    BookingVersion INT,
    flightId INT,
    shipmentNumber VARCHAR(20),
    shipmentDate DATE,
    FlightOffPoint VARCHAR(10),
    BookingStatusCode VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table 
VALUES(
4 ,              625436 ,     '61823647238',    '2019-12-04',  'LHR','XX'),
(2,               625436,     ' 61823647238',    '2019-12-04',  'LHR','SS'),
(1,               625436,     ' 61826374895',    '2019-12-06',  'LHR','XX'),
(0,               625436,     ' 61825364780',    '2019-11-26',  'LHR','SS'),
(0,               625436,     ' 61825364791',    '2019-11-26',  'LHR','SS'),
(0,               625436,     ' 61825364802',    '2019-11-26',  'LHR','SS'),
(0,               625436,     ' 61826374895',    '2019-12-06',  'LHR','SS')


SELECT MAX(BookingVersion) AS BookingVersion,
    flightId,
    shipmentNumber,
    shipmentDate,
    FlightOffPoint, 
    MAX(BookingStatusCode) AS BookingStatusCode
FROM @Table 
GROUP BY flightId, shipmentNumber, shipmentDate, FlightOffPoint
ORDER BY MAX(BookingVersion) DESC
```

> Output

[image]